# How to provide our customers ability to self service client certificate creation?

Tags: certificates, certificate-authority

We have an API for B2B customers to access our platform.
We require each B2B customer to have a client certificate. 
This is not the URL SSL certificate (https).
The CN of each customer's client certificate control access to specific content on our platform.
Up to now, we've wanted to control the creation of certificates (public and private) on behalf of the customer to streamline access, define and maintain the CN, and to manage expiry dates.
This means that we create public and private certificates for each customer and then pass them the private certificate to load on their system.
Not the way it should work.
To fix this, I'm thinking we act as the certificate authority for our customers, where we provide them a self service portal/system to create a client certificate pair (with some restrictions/definitions imposed by us).

Does anyone know if this means becoming a CA for our customers?
Do existing CAs offer a 'white label-like' service?

My apologies if I've asked a 'discussion question' vs an answerable question.
Not my intent.
Thanks,
-EC